# Django UpdateForm DateInput widget not showing date

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I'm using the DateInput widget to provide a datepicker when a date field is input. However on my update form, the form pulls all the data for that recordd, except the date, which shows up as:

```
dd/mm/yyy
```

How do I get the already input date to show"
models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    '''
    Main Project, serves the default Projects Portal window.
    '''
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        Area,
        related_name="project",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
        )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    others = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    staff_trials = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField()
    slip = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-slip", "deadline"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class ProjectModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form used for creating and editing projects. Authenticated User
    required to be signed in.
    """
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    summary = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'title',
            'summary',
            'others',
            'staff_trials',
            'deadline',
            'area',
        )
        widgets = {
            'staff_trials': DateInput(),
            'deadline': DateInput(),
        }
```

veiws.py

```
class ProjectEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'project_portal/project_detail.html'
    form_class = ProjectModelForm
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        form.instance.user = user
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_object(self):
        slug_ = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        return get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not define again `title` and `summary`. If you want to have a text area widget, just specify that in the `Meta` part of your form, it's cleaner. I do not think it is useful to override the default `forms.DateInput` in your case.

```py
class ProjectModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'title',
            'summary',
            'others',
            'staff_trials',
            'deadline',
            'area',
        )
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.Textarea(),
            'summary': forms.Textarea(),
            'staff_trials': forms.DateInput(),
            'deadline': forms.DateInput(),
        }
```

Finally, are you sure the good object is being used for your update view? Are the fields `title`, `summary` etc the ones expected?

---

**EDIT** : another solution, with `django-tempus-dominus` package, really useful and with a nice widget.

#### Install the widget

```sh
pip install django-tempus-dominus
```

Then, add the application `tempus_dominus` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

#### Use the widget in your form

```py
# forms.py

from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker
class ProjectModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'title',
            'summary',
            'others',
            'staff_trials',
            'deadline',
            'area',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'deadline': DatePicker(
                options={
                    'format': 'DD/MM/YYYY'
                },
                attrs={
                    'prepend': 'fa fa-calendar',
                },
            )
        }
```

You can add a lot of options to your `DatePicker` widget, have a look [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-tempus-dominus/) and [here](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/) for instance.

#### Update your template

Simply add `{{ form.media }}` in the template used to display your date. To display the date, you do not have to change anything: `{{ form.deadline }}`.

**Note** : do not forget to add missing resources if necessary! Like jQuery, Bootstrap4... Just have a look to resources specified in `<head></head>` in the doc.

#### Practical example (my own configuration)

For instance, here is how I do so any date can only be set with clicks (user can not type inside the date input):

```py
# forms.py

import datetime
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from tempus_dominus.widgets import DatePicker

sixteen_years_ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=16*365.24)
common_options_for_datetimepicker = {
    'icons': {
        'time': 'far fa-clock',
        'date': 'far calendar-alt',
        'up': 'fas fa-arrow-circle-up',
        'down': 'fas fa-arrow-circle-down',
        'previous': 'far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg',
        'next': 'far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-lg',
    },
    'widgetPositioning': {
        'vertical': 'bottom',
        'horizontal': 'left'
    },
    'ignoreReadonly': True,
}

class Signup_MixinForm(SignupForm):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SignupRegular_Form(Signup_MixinForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(
        required=True,
        initial=sixteen_years_ago,
        widget=DatePicker(
            options={
                **common_options_for_datetimepicker,
                'format': 'D/MM/YYYY',
                'maxDate': sixteen_years_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            },
            attrs={
                'prepend': 'fa fa-calendar',
                'size': 'large',
                'placeholder': _("Your birth date"),
                'readonly': 'readonly'
            },
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Ok, so removing the widgets part of the code removes the date picker functionality that I want. And if I remove title and summary from this, then the update form does not pull any data from the database and ends up as a CreateView type form instead of UpdateView form with the correct data pulled from the database.

Comment: If I inspect the html, I get this for the date field <input type="date" name="deadline" value="22/12/2019" required="" id="id_deadline"> so it looks like it should be displaying the correct date, it's just being overridden with "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: My apologize, effectively default widget for DateField is a TextField. I struggled a lot with displaying real date (just like you), I ended up using a `DatePicker` widget from `tempus_dominus` package (the widget is much better than the default one). If you are interested in using this solution, just tell me so I can update my answer with that!
Also, I don't understand why `title` and `summary` do not display any data, this does not sound right.

Comment: Yes please, I have been using as much builtin to django as I can while learning, but now is a good time to extend into add ons.

Comment: One last thing before I show you my solution: are your `settings` coherent with your local date formatting? For instance I've got: `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'`, `USE_I18N = True`, `USE_L10N = True`, `USE_TZ = True`

Comment: Pretty much, the only difference is I am using UTC timezone, but in UK, so technically correct. It can be changed to London if UTC will cause issues though.

Comment: I'm getting an "TemplateDoesNotExist at /si/another-test/edit/" error for the tempus_dominus/widget.html. I'm using Anaconda distribution of Python if that makes a difference. Not sure how to post the error page in a comment.

Comment: As it is an application, did you add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`? And sorry, I do really not know anything about Anaconda :/

Comment: Ok I've put it into installed apps, but I can't get it to work, there is no date picker now and no date either.

Comment: `{{ form.media }}` should be between `<head></head>`. Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, I did that, but nothing unfortunately. Do I need anything like jquery, as I am not currently using any javascript at all, so jquery is not declared anywhere? I'm happy to, I just haven't needed any up till now.

Comment: Oh right I assumed you got that stuff already, sorry. Have a look here: https://pypi.org/project/django-tempus-dominus/, check the resources imported in `<head></head>`! You need Fontawesome (icons), Bootstrap4 and jQuery to render properly the widget.

Comment: Yup, brilliant, I get all that now. Thanks for your help, I'll work through this and learn it properly and give you a tick when I get this going.

Comment: Great! I will update my answer, and give you a more detailed one of my own configuration!

Comment: Sorry for the unbelievably late reply, but I have now come back to this issue and only just seen your updated reply, I shall look into all of this and give you an accepted answer tick when I've got to grips with it. Thank you very much for your time to write this.